# Can two 4G USB dongles connect directly?

Tags: usb, dongle, cellular-internet

I have two Huawei E3372 4G USB dongles. Each is plugged into a laptop.

Can two 4G USB dongles connect directly? I.e. Can I call one with the other to establish a connection, using its phone number?

They would then operate as radio modems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both modems have signal, a SIM card, and credit, etc... then it may **appear** that yes, they can communicate "*directly*"... However the cellular network is a critical part of the link.

Depending on your use of the term "*directly*", then our responses may vary:

- If you took two cellular (3G, 4G, etc...) modems to a remote location with no signal, then they would be completely unable to communicate with each other.
- If you took two serviceable cellular modems (signal, SIM, credit, etc...) and attempted to establish a data connection (e.g: TCP/IP) from one to the other, then your success may vary depending on the host network's infrastructure, topology and security.
- If you took two serviceable cellular modems and attempted to connect a voice / audio call from one to the other using the phone number, then it should work (call barring and other configuration permitting)

Answer (score 3):

No, they cannot. 4G doesn't work like that.